# How to get a polyline for shortest path between two points in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, shortest-path, polyline

I am new in leaflet and I need to create a **layer** for shortest path between nodes. I also need the polyline for some other calculations.
I tried some plugins which just display the shortest path on map but does not provide furthur details(polyline, point-to-point ...) for the optimal route.
Is there any way that I can get the data? any plugin or trick ...?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you have nodes on a graph, do you need the geodesic great circle, do you mean multi-modal routing?

Comment: Let's say it this way, I have two addresses and I want shortest path between these two (like my home and my office).

Comment: Walking, car, cycle, bus, or straight line (line of sight / carrier pigeon / flying drone)?

Comment: car , sorry about confusion :)))

Comment: I am using openstreetmap for the other parts by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use some geocoding (see http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding ) to turn addresses into lat-lng coordinates, then route finding ( http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing ) to find the shortest path constrained by a street network.

> I tried some plugins which just display the shortest path on map but does not provide furthur details

Then don't use a routing plugin and use the routing APIs (OSRM, GraphHopper, MapBox directions) directly. It will obviously involve more work but you will have a finer control.