# Leaflet: a line from New Zealand to Australia goes around the world

Tags: leaflet

My map is big enough so it shows New Zealand and Australia twice. Sometimes, Leaflet decides the best line line between them should go all around the world. Can I tell it to use the shortest possible route?

Comment: Your question was already asked. You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140647/how-to-get-a-polyline-for-shortest-path-between-two-points-in-leaflet

Comment: That's the answer on how to find an optimal path with a polyline. I just need one line. The problem is that if for instance Australia is shown twice on the map, I want Leaflet to select the closest one.

Comment: Can you post some example code where this happens?